# Maintain scroller position on Div after page postback (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a div as such:

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 260px">
```

I contains a few hundred records and allows me to select an item to populate a formview control below it.

The problem is that when the page posts-back, the scroller position  goes back to the top of the div. I want to try and maintain its position so that the selected record is still visible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Place something like:

```
 <asp:HiddenField id="hdnScrollPos" runat="server"/> in your aspx.
```

Then, some javascript like:

```
var hdnScroll = document.getElementById(<%=hdnScrollPos.ClientID%>);
var bigDiv = document.getElementById('bigDiv');
bigDiv.onscroll = function() {
     hdnScroll.value = bigDiv.scrollTop;
}

window.onload = function () { 
    bigDiv.scrollTop = hdnScroll.value;
}
```

Comment: I found it necessary to have `var hdnScroll = document.getElementById('hdnScrollPos');
` rather than that shown, but thanks all the same.

Comment: Remember to put ViewStateMode="Enabled" if you have disabled it globally

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more refined way of FlySwat's solution using JQuery which worked for me:

```
    var $ScrollPosition = $('#hfScrollPosition');
    var $ScrollingDiv = $('#pnlGroupDataContent');
    if ($ScrollPosition.length && $ScrollingDiv.length) {
        // Store scrolling value
        $ScrollingDiv.scroll(function () {
            $ScrollPosition.val($ScrollingDiv.scrollTop());
        });
        // Set scrolling
        $ScrollingDiv.scrollTop($ScrollPosition.val());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer - not my code, but I've seen this used before:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var strCook = document.cookie;
    if(strCook.indexOf("!~")!=0){
      var intS = strCook.indexOf("!~");
      var intE = strCook.indexOf("~!");
      var strPos = strCook.substring(intS+2,intE);

      document.getElementById("divTest").scrollTop = strPos;
      document.getElementById("divTest").scrollTop = strPos;
    }
  }
  function SetDivPosition(){
    var intY = document.getElementById("divTest").scrollTop;

    document.cookie = "yPos=!~" + intY + "~!";
  }
```

The idea is to store the position of the scrollbar in a cookie. Another (better?) option would be to store it in a hidden field (or fields). Hope that gets you going...

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET has this built in all you need to do is include the MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback in your page directive.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

Comment: I doubt that works on embedded divs, just the main page in general.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure this will work on DIV's contained within the page. Although I haven't tried it.

Comment: FYI this appears to only work for early versions of IE.

Comment: This works only on main page and not on embedded divs.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `thebody` with `document.getElementById("divTest")`

If you worry that the onscroll event does not work in opera/ff, you can try changing

```
thebody.onscroll=SaveScrollLocation;
```

to

```
setInterval('SaveScrollLocation()", 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried all of the above and none of them worked satisfactorily in chrome v39, however the method used on this page worked marvellously:

[Maintain Scroll Position of DIV on PostBack in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Maintain-Scroll-Position-of-DIV-on-PostBack-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfScroll" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            ScrollMaintain();
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                $('#hfScroll').val($(window).scrollTop());
            });

        function ScrollMaintain() {
            var scroll = $('#hfScroll').val();
            scroll = (scroll == '' ? '0' : scroll);
            $(window).scrollTop(scroll);
        }
    </script>
```