# How to scroll to selected in a DataGrid?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I'm displaying a Datagrid like this and inviting the user to make a selection...

```
<div id="gradesDiv" style="overflow: auto; width: 380px; height: 300px">
    <asp:DataGrid id="gradesGrid"
                  BorderWidth="1"
                  CellPadding="3"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="true"
                  runat="server">
        <Columns>
             <asp:ButtonColumn HeaderText="Select&nbsp;Item"
                               ButtonType="LinkButton"
                               Text="Select"
                               CommandName="Select">
             </asp:ButtonColumn>
        </Columns>
    </asp:DataGrid>
 </div>
```

(three other columns are added in the code-behind). But when the user makes a selection, a postback is performed and the scroll position lost. I'd like to be able to reset the div to display the selected item. Does anyone know how to do this?

I've tried adding

```
MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"
```

to the asp, but it doesn't help. I attempted to maintain the scroll position in the codebehind but gradesDiv does not appear to be available to the code-behind.

Comment: If you're using .NET 4.0 you could try setting gridview's `EnablePersistedSelection="true"`

Comment: @deni, thanks for the suggestion: I am using .Net 4.0, but it doesn't work if I put it in either the DataGrid or the div.

Comment: Put the datagrid in an update panel

Comment: I found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184576/maintain-scroller-position-on-div-after-page-postback-asp-net), once I noticed that it is the `div` needing scrolling and not the `DataGrid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few creative approaches on the web on how this can be done.Just search for  - *maintaining div scroll position on postback*.This is just one of such examples:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var xPos, yPos;
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
        prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

        var divId = 'gradesDiv';

        function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            xPos = $get(divId).scrollLeft;
            yPos = $get(divId).scrollTop;
        }
        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            $get(divId).scrollLeft = xPos;
            $get(divId).scrollTop = yPos;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this fails with `Microsoft JScript runtime error: object expected`

Comment: Could you specify at which line is it failing?

Comment: so far as I can tell, the `$(document).ready(function (){` is the problem.

Comment: Did you add a reference to the jQuery library in the <head> section?

Comment: no, I didn't. That's probably the reason, then. I won't be able to try it for a while. Thanks again for your help.